# iphone icon sizes compared to on photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, interface-design, apple

I noticed the apple guidelines mentions that app icons are 120x120 but when I go to something like photoshop or fireworks to see how that looks like, it looks much bigger than that. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with the pixel density on the iPhone or other smartphone screens. iPhone 6 Plus has 401 pixels per inch, it is probably 4 times the density on your computer monitor. In other words, 120 pixels will be a tad over an inch on your computer monitor but will be about 0.3" on the iPhone display.

Comment: So when designing icons on something such as photoshop,fireworks,etc what size should we be designing the icons then?

Comment: There are guidelines I'm sure for Googling. I would search for something like "design guidelines for retina display iphones" and see what comes up.